# What's the effect of breaking lights?

Tags: payday-2

In some maps, you can break light bulbs or wall lights (I'm thinking about the [Framing Frame](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Framing_Frame) heist, day 3, on the rooftop).

[image: Shooting at a light bulb]

[image: Shooting at wall lights]

Does it have any effect ?  Obviously, ambient light around the broken source of light seriously dimmed: does it help to remain stealthy ?  Could it be used to lure a guard (I don't have any practical example in mind, but still) ?

Comment: Honestly, considering the way visibility works in this game (if you have armor on the lobby guard can just about see you when you spawn in Framing Frame 1), I doubt that shooting out lights has any effect. I could be wrong.

Comment: I would assume it leaves broken glass on the ground, like a broken window, which would alert guards who find it.

Comment: @MichaelCampbell How would this be an advantage to the player?

Comment: Well if it allows the player to lure one of the guards, it's definitely an advantage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### There is no effect.

---

#### Part 1: Does light affect the visibility of the player?

To test this, I soloed my way to Framing Frame Day 3.  With my silenced pistol in hand, I waited for a guard to come by.  When he spotted me, I killed him.  Then I shot out all the lights on the roof.  When the next guard came by, I stood in the same place and waited.  He was standing in the same place as the previous guard when he died.

***Result of stealth test: Light has no effect on player visibility.***

---

#### Part 2: Does light (or the absence of it) cause guards to become curious?

After my previous test, no guard seemed to want to come up to the roof.  I reloaded the mission and again soloed to the third day.  When a guard arrived on the roof, I used my <strike>water arrows</strike> silenced pistol to shoot out the lights near him.

***Result of attention test: Broken lights have no effect on guard attention.***

---

#### Part 3: Extra Credit:

Then, since I was there, I started to wonder if there was *anything* I could shoot that would bother him...

**List of things that guards do not notice .45 caliber bullets going into:**

- Lights
- Tables
- Roofs
- Plants
- The floor right in front of them
- The space between their knees

**List of things that guards *do* notice .45 caliber bullets going into:**

- Cameras
- Windows
- Themselves